# Подключение к MySQL в локальной сети

Tags: mysql

Как подключиться к серверу по локальной сети через dbForge Studio for MySQL, или HeidiSQL, или Navicat for MySQL? А может быть есть, что-то попроще?

Answer (score 2):

Конфиг в `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`. Там есть секция, отвечающая за прослушиваемые интерфейсы:

```
bind-address            = 0.0.0.0        # слушать все интерфейсы
```

Подробнее: [--bind-address=addr](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_bind-address).

Comment: Этого можно и не писать, так как это значение по-умолчанию.@виктор54, проверьте в конфиге опцию `skip-networking`, ее не должно быть (законметирована)

Answer (score 0):

Видел в mysql workbench возможность подключения через ssh. Т.е. будете соединяться с базой поверх ssh, посмотрите, возможно там есть такой вариант.

Если нет, то на сервере mysql в конфиге надо разрешить слушать и другие сетевые интерфейсы, помимо локального, чтобы с ним могли соединятся через интернет или lan.

Comment: Спасибо. По локалхост проблемы нет. Сервер комп1, нужно к нему подключится с комп2. Если честно, то я не знаю, где искать конфиг.