# Подключение к БД (mySQL) по сети - Delphi

Tags: mysql, delphi, клиент-сервер, adoconnection

Есть элемент ADOConnection, в нём строка подключения к БД (*БД на MySQL*):

> "Provider=MSDASQL.1;Persist Security Info=False;Extended
>   Properties="Driver=MySQL ODBC 5.2 Unicode
>   Driver;SERVER=localhost;UID=root;DATABASE=[DB-name];PORT=3306"

Всё работает отлично, но это на локальном ПК. А я разрабатываю клиент-серверное ПО, то есть необходимо подключится клиенту удалённо к БД.
Как надо переписать строку подключения, чтобы подключиться к БД по сети?
Или как-то надо расшарить доступ к БД mySQL?
Или для доступа по сети необходим совершенно другой инструмент подключения?

---

При подстановки в `Server=...` ip-адреса ПК с БД, драйвер выдаёт:
`Can't connection to mySQL server on [ip-адрес] (10061)`

---

Примечание: порт 3306 открыт (так как другие БД работают через интернет)
Дополнение: наглядная визуализация проблемы.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

РЕШЕНИЕ!
В файле конфигурации mySQL - my.ini (на локальной машине), делаем так:

```
# bind-address = 127.0.0.1
bind-address = 0.0.0.0
port         = 3306
```

P.S. благодаря [ответу](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/341735/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BA-mysql-%D0%B2-%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8) пользователя [post_ed](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/6526/post-ed)

Answer (score 1):

Замените значение параметра `SERVER` на адрес вашего сервера, например:

> SERVER=MyServer.ru;

или

> SERVER=195.134.85.12;

Comment: Было бы несложно догадаться, что это первое, что приходит в голову программисту.
Только такая попытка выдаёт: `Can't connection to mySQL server on [ip-address] (10061)`

Comment: @I_CaR Смотрите настройки MySQL, там по умолчанию разрешены только локальные подключения.

Comment: Спасибо. Об этом я и подумал, когда после вашего ответа попытался приконнектиться по ip через менеджер БД (Navicat). Вот как-то не приходилось делать ни разу разрешение на удалённый доступ.
Буду ковырять в этом направлении!